# how to workaround a deadlock (multithreading a program)

Tags: bash, multithreading, gnu-parallel

I need to run a program 100 times, a few hours each, which is fine when running it in a serial way, just takes very long, but when I try to parallelize it using GNU parallel or simple '&' in bash, it hangs/freezes, i suspect a deadlock, but I have not written the program so cannot debug it.

I guess there is little chance, but is there a way perhaps an easy way to run an application in some sort of isolation or quarantaine from everything else on linux? (without  going for multiple virtualboxes :P )

Answer (score 1):

What is this program doing - do you know what it's using (shared mem, mutexes, maybe files with the same name and every instance is overwriting it, you could check in tmp directory). Tried to **strace** it?

Don't know the scale of your problem but you could use **Docker** - https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Docker to create lightweight containers or take a look at **QubesOs** to create isolated environments https://qubes-os.org/ or try to use this program in **chrooted** environment

Answer (score 0):

As KaP says: strace it. You can start the strace when it hangs by using -p.

Can you reproduce the problem if running as different users (each user runs a single copy)?

If you are lucky then the program only deadlocks when programs are started at the same time. If that is the case use '--delay' in GNU Parallel to delay starting the next job.